# How to index a DateTimeIndex with a label list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I am having troubles indexing a pandas dataframe with pandas.DatetimeIndex index.

The problem arises when i try to index the dataframe with a list of labels, using `.loc` accessor (on the contrary, indexing with a list of indexes through `.iloc` works).

Here is the code to reproduce the issue:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = StringIO("""
timestamp,value
2014-04-02 14:29:00,42.652
2014-04-02 14:34:00,41.361
2014-04-02 14:39:00,-68.408
2014-04-02 14:44:00,40.262
2014-04-02 14:59:00,-89.836
2014-04-02 15:04:00,42.579
""")

anomalies = ['2014-04-02 14:39:00', '2014-04-02 14:59:00']

df = pd.read_csv(data, parse_dates=['timestamp'], index_col='timestamp')

# Works
print("1)")
print(df.loc[anomalies[0]])
print(df.loc[anomalies[1]])

# Works
print("\n2)")
anomalies_indexes = [np.argwhere(df.index == a).item() for a in anomalies]
print(anomalies_indexes)  # prints [2, 4]
print(df.iloc[anomalies_indexes, :])

# Does not work -> throws KeyError
print("\n3)")
print(df.loc[anomalies, :])
```

I am using Python `3.7.2` and pandas `0.23.4` on my machine, but the same behavior happens on Repl.it with Python `3.7.4` and pandas `0.25.1` (try this [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/IntentBreakableSigns)) and with Python `2.7.16` and pandas `0.24.2` (try this [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DarkvioletVoluminousConversions)), which are the default versions for Python 2 and 3 environments on Repl.it at the time of writing.

Can you spot any error in my code or tell me what I am missing?

**[EDIT: Answer]**

The solution is to convert the strings in datetime objects, as suggested in the comments (thanks to user @anky_91):

```py
anomalies = [pd.to_datetime(a) for a in anomalies]
print(df.loc[anomalies, :])  # Now this works
```

Comment: that is because the list `anomalies` has string entries but the `df.index` is a datetimeindex, try `df.loc[[pd.to_datetime(i) for i in anomalies]]` to see that works

Comment: @anky_91 yes that was the problem. I can't say I did not think about it, but as indexing with a single string worked, I expected it to work with a list, so I did not try.. Shame on me. And thank you guys for the fast answer.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(anomalies)` would work as well.